# Error Conflict with dependency in android studio

Tags: android-studio-3.0

I am getting this error in android studio when i try to create a new project. Please help me step to step to deal with it. I am completely new to this IDE. [ERROR SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecDs5.jpg)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution myself, I'd like to leave it here.

Open android studio.
On the left side that project menu (files explorer type)
there will be a option "gradle scripts" clicking on it opens the drop down menu.

There will be a file **build.gradle** (Module:app)
Double click it, It would open in android studio.

Change to the following in settings:
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Sync the files in gradle. You're done.
Android studio would download the files if required.