# Conflict with dependency in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (15.0.2) and test app (12.0.1) differ (possibly onesignal&firebase issue)

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, onesignal

I cant seem to build gradle for my app on Android Studio 3.0.1 (generate apk works). Below was the build output.

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Conflict with dependency 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging' in project ':app'. 
Resolved versions for app (15.0.2) and test app (12.0.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 23s
```

[Here](https://gist.github.com/axilaris/3151780bfddc5efbf8f1928d2874230f) is the build.gradle file contents.

UPDATE 21.8.2018:

I notice in the external libraries, I have a conflict

[image]

I found out that I can generate the apk (Build APK) eventhough gradle produce the conflict error. The way to remove gradle error is to remove/comment this line:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
```

but then APK wont compile. It used to work, I realized this problem may have happened after I had to include Firebase in another project (cordova based Android app) that used the same Android Studio. This problem does not happen to my other colleague machine. How do I really solve this ? Thanks

Comment: Please update your post to include both the project and app module `build.gradle` files.

Comment: i;ved added the build.gradle file

Comment: @Axil I cannot see in your build.gradle file this line of code: `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. Are you missing it? Please responde with @.

Comment: @AlexMamo it was never there. i tried adding that line but it came out this: Error:(14, 0) Plugin with id 'com.google.gms.google-services' not found.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Conflict with dependency in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50334435/error-conflict-with-dependency-in-android-studio)

Comment: What's your gradle version ?

Comment: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'

Comment: Did you find any solution? As I am also having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your build.gradle file.  But without seeing it my guess is that you have an `implementation` and `testImplementation` that have different versions for `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging`

Comment: i;ved added the build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

Try to force the version of your firebase dependency using below configuration

```
android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    }
}
```

Comment: i;ved added the build.gradle file just in case

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a transitive dependency issue. Both `com.google.android.gms:play-services` and `com.onesignal:OneSignal` use `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging`, but they're probably importing different versions. I'd recommend upgrade to use the latest versions of these libraries.

Comment: Hmm.... it used to work on my Android Studio. Something caused it to messed up in this case. Upgrading, im not sure since I'ved got a programmer doing this so it may be an issue. Is there a better way of handling this, it works with other Android Studio, what Im trying to do is to recover back the environment for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there are two libraries that depend on firebase-messaging library, and they're depending on different versions. To find out which ones they are, go to Terminal window in your Android Studio and run this command:

> ./gradlew app:dependencies

That'll show you all the dependencies in your project in a tree structure. Once you detect which libraries add the duplicate library, you can try one of these:

1) Check for the other versions of the parent dependencies in your build.gradle which both use the same version of the transitive duplicate dependency.

2) Exclude the dependency with the lower version from the parent dependency. Example:

```
  implementation('com.example.abc:def:1.0.0') {
     exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-messaging' 
  }
```

3) Enforce a fixed version w/ a resolution strategy:

```
configurations.all {
  resolutionStrategy { 
     force com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependency **OneSignal** is **using old version** of `play-service`.

You have these ways to solve this.

- Exclude `play-service` from OneSignal and force to use the latest- you are using. (As [@gizembrh answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51967412/6891563)). (**I dont suggest, because OneSignal's code may crash with new play-service**)
- Download the OneSignal sdk and put that as a module in your project. Then update OneSignal's play-service version, solve it's deprecated methods(if any). (**Lengthy work**)
- Downgrade your `play-service` version as same version of OneSignal. (**The easiest I think**)

I think 3rd option best suits to you. Because you just need to downgrade your play-service version. See **[OneSignal `build.gradle` play-service version](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/app/build.gradle)**

```
def playServicesVersion = '12.0.0'
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:$playServicesVersion"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"
```

Also use in your project level **build.gradle**, use below version of `google-services`. See **[OneSignal `build.gradle` google-services version](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/blob/master/OneSignalSDK/build.gradle).**

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

**If you do above both changes in your gradle, you will not face this error any more.**

Comment: sorry, very busy.i still cant get it working. here are my changes and error. https://gist.github.com/axilaris/cafe8f87ff17ba3a394834317a500d6c

Comment: similar but slightly different, now its complaining version '12.0.0'

Comment: Did you try running project?

Comment: u mean build apk, that works fine. it can build. btw, on a different Android Studio it works. the problem is just on my machine (which it used to work)

Comment: Okay, then no problem, if you can run project, then go ahead!

Comment: im just very uncomfortable with this. i want to fix this gradle issue on my machine.

Comment: if i remove the implementation lines, gradle will work but then it will complain on unable to build the apk

Comment: is there a cleaning process ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178779/discussion-between-axil-and-khemraj).